# .NET 2.0 and Classic ASP running on Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp-classic, .net-2.0, named-pipes, iis-8

I really hope someone can help out.  We are in the process of migrating all of our web applications to a new hosting environment.

Most of the applications are .NET 4 / 4.5.  However we have a few running .NET and one running classic ASP.

On all the sites running .NET 2.0 we are getting:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

The connection string points to the DB server by IP address - not name.

I'm also getting a 500 error on the classic ASP - but I am still working on the specific error.  My suspicion is they are the same - mainly because it takes 30 seconds for both apps (classic ASP / .NET 2.0) to render the error page.

The new environment is Server 2012.  They are coming from a server 2008 environment.

Is there something about IIS 8.5 that needs to be set-up to all the db access on older framework apps?

Comment: Can you post your connection strings - (without the real IP address, obviously)?

Comment: You'll want to set up a separate application pool as "Managed pipeline mode=Classic" for your classic ASP application.